# how to get notified in react native if specific folder have file created or deleted

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs

hello i am new in `React-Native`
i have application that Download Multyple Files from `URL` and Store in aplication storage
and Display it in `FlatList`

i use `StackNavigator` for display two tab

first Tab for Display Running/progress Download Files List

and Second Tab for Display Finished downloaded Files List

i used `react-native-fs` for download files from url

and get files list from download path for display in list

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([{}]);

RNFS.readDir(appFolderPath)
  .then(files => {
      setFileList(files);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
  });
```

this called infinite because everytime setFileList(files); set files and its refresh screen

how to get notyfied only and only if any download is finish or folder have new file ?